# Save JSON file on Dropbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dropbox

Is there any option to save JSON file after it is created/encode from PHP on Dropbox, with Javascript, jQuery or something else? Can you give any hints?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: It is not hard to hit at this address, If i found something I did not ask specific question...

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: Maybe there is somewhere a library or tutorial for this, maybe someone made something like this, i just want some advice, not lessons how to use google...

Comment: There is a tutorial right here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server where php generates your json, you can install dropbox there using this http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment tutorial. after this you can use dropbox cli api from this tutorial http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli to determine if it is running and run if it is not (you can use php exec function for this). after this just copy (using php copy function) the file which contains json to your dropbox folder